# Count the number of cycles in a CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

How can I count the number of cycles performed by a function like the following. Should I count straight forward the number of sums and muls and divs? Where can I check how many cycles an addition takes in CUDA?

```
__global__
void mandelbrotSet_per_element(Grayscale *image){
    float minR = -2.0f, maxR = 1.0f;
    float minI = -1.2f, maxI = minI + (maxR-minR) * c_rows / c_cols;
    float realFactor = (maxR - minR) / (c_cols-1);
    float imagFactor = (maxI - minI) / (c_rows-1);

    bool isInSet;
    float c_real, c_imag, z_real, z_imag;

    int y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    while (y < c_rows){
        while (x < c_cols) {
            c_real = minR + x * realFactor;
            c_imag = maxI - y * imagFactor;
            z_real = c_real;    z_imag = c_imag;
            isInSet = true;

            for (int k = 0; k < c_iterations; k++){
                float z_real2 = z_real * z_real;
                float z_imag2 = z_imag * z_imag;
                if (z_real2 + z_imag2 > 4){
                    isInSet = false;
                    break;
                }
                z_imag = 2 * z_real * z_imag + c_imag;
                z_real = z_real2 - z_imag2 + c_real;
            }
            if (isInSet)    image[y*c_cols+x] = 255;
            else            image[y*c_cols+x] = 0;

            x += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
        }
        x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
        y += blockDim.y * gridDim.y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instruction throughput is described in the programming guide [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#maximize-instruction-throughput)

You can also try measuring a sequence of instructions using the native `clock()` function described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function)

The compiler tends to obscure actual counts of operations at the source code level (increasing or possibly decreasing apparent arithmetic intensity) so if you want to indentify exactly what the machine is doing you may want to inspect the ptx (nvcc -ptx ...) or possibly the machine assembly level code, called SASS, which you can extract from an executable using the `cuobjdump` utility.

Comment: Very much appreciated. So for examples if the kernel does 8 additions, the number of cycles needed is 8/32 ? According to the instruction throughput?

Comment: If the kernel does 8 SP FP additions *in a single thread, i.e. in sequence*, running on a CC 2.0 device, and ignoring other factors such as ILP, data stalls, register contention, stupid compiler tricks, etc., then it should require 8 clocks, or stated more correctly, the SM can retire 1 add per clock (that's what *throughput* is).  If all the threads in a warp are executing the same 8 adds, it takes no longer (with the same caveats).  If only 8 of the threads in the warp are executing the same 8 adds, it takes no less time.